# Most concise way to define multiple variables

Tags: python

I have data consisting of about 10,000 entries. Each row is a price for a product in a specific currency. For example:

```
- Purchase 1 = 10.25 USD
- Purchase 2 = 11.76 SEK
```

I have ten different database columns to total sales for each currency (this is a requirement). The columns are `earnings_in_usd`, `earnings_in_sek`, `earnings_in_eur`, etc. In my function to do an insert statement to the database, I need to define the necessary variable. By default all other entries will be 0.00. This is basically the code that would accomplish what I need to do:

```
if currency == 'USD':
    earnings_in_usd = value
elif currency == 'SEK':
    earnings_in_sek = value
elif ...
```

Is there a more straightforward way to do this (a way do to something like earnings_in_$ = value)?

Comment: Do you mean you are forced to set those specific variables? As in that they are the interface to the next step of the system and not just internal, and you will interact with other parts using function calls or the like?

Comment: (late edit) What I mean is that they are the interface to the next step of the system, as opposed to that you will interact with other parts using function calls or the like. Is that (the former) the case?

Comment: @Emil I'm not certain I understand you question, but no the values are not used at a later time in the function. They are only needed to insert into the database.

Comment: What I mean is do you have to use those exact variables or could you use, say, a single dictionary instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict` indexed by the currency.

```
from collections import defaultdict

earnings = defaultdict(float)  # float has a default value of 0.
```

Instead of your long if-then-else, use this single line:

```
earnings[currency] = value
```

and retrieve the earnings in, say, US$, with

```
earnings["USD"]
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please show me an example of how I would use the `defaultdict` for a single value -- for example, if `currency='AUD'`, the variable I need to define is `earnings_in_aud`, and the value would be 10.00.

Comment: @David542: don't define that variable. Just say `earnings[currency] = 10.00` and then query it using `print(earnings[currency])`.

Comment: @David542: You can also use the dict in stringformatting:  `"INSERT INTO ... (%(USD)s, %(SEK)s, %(AUD)s)" % earnings`   (or `"... {USD} ..".format(**earnings)`)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a dictionary?

```
earnings = {}
earnings[currency] = value
```

Comment: This is probably the preferred solution if it's possible to do this in this use case.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, which may very well have someone confounded when it breaks, is to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
earnings_in_usd, earnings_in_sek, ... = [(value if currency == c else 0) for c in CURRENCIES]
```

The drawback is that the left hand side would have to include all your variables, and CURRENCIES would have to be a list of string constants with exactly the same order as the variables on the left hand side. Like I said, this may very well break if you tamper with other parts of the program...

Comment: I believe Python would look askance at that syntax.

Comment: Oh, right. In Python the ternary operator doesn't exist but can be emulated using `and` and `or`. Answer updated.

Comment: In Python "the ternary operator" is `value1 if condition else value2`

Comment: ...from version 2.5? I've used versions 2.7 and 3! How did I miss that? :O

Answer (score -1):

If earnings is an object/array then

```
earnings[currency] = value
```

or

```
earnings.currency = value;
```